# Can I set a remite branch as the push upstream of my local main?

Tags: git

I worked on my main branch instead of creating a new one. I committed some changes to it. I then created a local branch and checked it out. My changes are not there, as they are in the main branch. Can I simply go back to my local main and set it to push to the correct remote upstream branch and then push to achieve adding my changes to the branch and not the main?

Answer (score 1):

If I understand this correctly,

1. You were in `main`
2. You did some work
3. You made some commits
4. You then checked out a new branch

If that's the correct and complete sequence of events, then the new branch contains the new commits. Push away.

Answer (score 1):

How did you create the local branch?  The commits being there depends where you set the HEAD on the new branch. If you want to add your local changes from `main` to your new branch you can use `git merge main` when you have the new local branch checked out

```
git checkout <new local branch>
git merge main
```

Then you can push your local branch upstream to the remote as a new branch to create a PR to `main`

```
git push -u origin HEAD
```

That should get you where you want to be.